# All pages Redirecting to one page .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am getting problem with .htaccess ... all my pages are getting redirect to one page

here is my .htaccess

EDITED

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesmatch \.(css|html|js|php|xml)$>
        setoutputfilter deflate
    </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^about-trust(.*)$ /trust_detail.php?id=no$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^college(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=college$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^trust(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=trust$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^academy(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=academy$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^press(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=press$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

all my pages are getting redirect to  gallery.php like if i try to open trust_detail.php its also getting redirect to gallery.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this problem because you're not using `L` (Last) flag. Change your code to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^about-trust(.*)$ /trust_detail.php?id=no$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^college(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=college$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^trust(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=trust$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^academy(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=academy$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^press(.*)$ /gallery.php?type=press$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: OK what URI did you try to test? And what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: here is url i am trying to access http://grdpunjab.com/about-trust its getting redirect to gallery.php

Comment: This URI is first getting rewritten to `/trust_detail.php?id=no` and then since it will match `^trust(.*)$` it will further be rewritten to  `/gallery.php?type=trust`

Comment: i have tried RewriteRule ^about(.*)$ /trust_detail.php?id=no$1 [L,QSA] this also but no luck ... i have remove trust from about-trust ;(

Comment: You are still not getting it. Try out my edited answer and see if it works. If it works I will explain it later.

Comment: thx mate it worked other way around , i have change file name from trust_detail to about_detail and every thing work smooth :)